# How to get PHP to read the JSON array name INSTEAD of the content within the array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need help getting PHP to read an array name INSTEAD of the content in the array.

I am using PHP to parse a JSON response from an API call. 
If the user inputs something incorrectly the JSON will respond with 
`array(1) { ["error"]=> ...`
If the API request is successful the JSON that is returned is
`array(2) { ["message"]=> ...`

This would be easy if the API provided a `["success"]=true/false`, but instead it provides two completely different response on success or failure so I need PHP to be able to read the array names, instead of the array content.

I want to create an if statement in PHP based on the array name. I can pull the message from error or the message from message just fine, but I want PHP to check to see what the array title is called. I was thinking something like this...

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
if ($response[] == "error"){
echo "There was an error: ".$response["error"];
} else {
echo $response["message"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you should test that the key is present in array

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

if(isset($response["error"])) { // errror }
if(isset($response["message"])) { // ok }
```